# Onclick count the object that return by JSON in Jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have a list of link , when I click on it , I want to count the elements that contain in my list. This is what I coded:

```
$('a#' + dataOption.ID).click(function () {
  $.getJSON("ProductListing/Index", data, function (product) {
     $.each(product.ja, function (index, value) {
        num_obj = product.ja.length;
     });
  });
});
alert(num_obj);
```

The alert is Undefined.

The JSON result is :

```
{"ja":
[
   {"Name":"ABC1","PictureName1":"my image name1","ID":1},   
   {"Name":"ABC2","PictureName2":"my image name2","ID":2}
]}
```

Could anyone tell me, how can I count that JSON in my click event. Thans so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've posted creates a click handler and then immediately does an `alert(num_obj)` - given that `num_obj` isn't declared anywhere and the click event itself hasn't happened yet, `num_obj` is *supposed* to be undefined at that point.

Try moving the alert into the callback of the `$.getJSON()` function, to just after the first point where `num_obj` actually has a value assigned:

```
$('a#' + dataOption.ID).click(function () {
  $.getJSON("ProductListing/Index", data, function (product) {
     var num_obj = product.ja.length;
     alert(num_obj);
  });
});
```

Note that I've removed the `$.each()` since it doesn't make sense to iterate over the `product.ja` array and test `product.ja.length` for each element (the fact that you didn't use `this` or `index` or `value` inside the `$.each()` was also a clue that you didn't need the each).